# Como posso encontrar o utilizador no Ubuntu (Shell/Bash)

Tags: linux, shell, bash, cmd

Pretendo criar um sistema que deve de forma interactiva encontrar o utilizador e posteriormente dizer se o mesmo existe ou não. Eu devo fornecer o nome de utilizador e se o utilizador for encontrado então o sistema encontrou o nome de utilizador e entra, se não diz que houve um erro

Preciso de fazer algo do género (em pseudo-código):

```
erro<-"O utilizador nao foi encontrado"
escreve ("Introduza nome de utilizador")
lê nome
se (nome==encontrado)
{
  ... entra no sistema
}
senao
{
     escreve ($erro)
}
```

em Bash no Linux Ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/bash
erro="Utilizador não encontrado"
echo "Qual o utilizador que pretende encontrar?"
read user

if[user  (encontrado)]#duvida
{
   ....
}
else
{
   echo $erro
}
fi
```

Comment: Onde vai estar a "base de dados" de utilizadores? Você pretende usar o /etc/passwd e validar se o usuário/utilizadores existe lá dentro ou terá outra base de utilizadores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O script correto pode ser executado dessa forma, de preferencia como root

```
#!/bin/bash
erro="Utilizador não encontrado"
echo "Qual o utilizador que pretende encontrar?"
read user
if [ `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d \: -f1 | grep $user`  ] ; then
....
else
echo $erro
fi
```