# Como fazer um reset na senha do bash Ubuntu do windows 10?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-10

Não me recordo da senha do meu usuário do bash do Ubuntu no Windows 10 como faço para criar uma nova senha para meu usuário?

Comment: Não entendi porque vocês acharam fora de escopo. Saber fazer um reset de senha do meu usuário do bash do Ubuntu do Windows-10 me parece um conhecimento não só útil como relacionado ao tema de programação. Vocês podem ser um pouco mais específicos porque fora do escopo?

Comment: Para mim entra em _Ferramentas normalmente usadas por desenvolvedores exercendo sua função programando, depurando, preparando ou implantando softwares e controlando o processo._

Tem essa pergunta que acho que se a minha é fora de escopo está também é [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91887/como-posso-encontrar-o-utilizador-no-ubuntu-shell-bash?rq=1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91887/como-posso-encontrar-o-utilizador-no-ubuntu-shell-bash?rq=1)

Comment: Se você acha que está dentro do escopo, existe o botão **reabrir** logo abaixo da pergunta. Se mais 4 pessoas concordarem, a pergunta será reaberta. Se você acha que esta outra que citou também estaria fora do escopo, para isso há o botão **sinalizar** e, da mesma forma, se outros usuários concordarem, será fechada. É assim que funciona a comunidade.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se possível, tente desinstalar o Ubuntu, e então reinstale, então ele pedirá novamente os dados para criar o usuário.

```
lxrun /uninstall /full 

lxrun /install
```

Fonte: https://superuser.com/a/1065579/274615

Comment: Quem deu downvote provavelmente não examinou a fundo as opções possíveis.

Comment: Acredito que o downvote tem a ver com a pergunta ser offtopic, só a fonte que voce achou ja comprovaria isso.

Comment: Não é off-topic, pois o StackOverflow também engloba o uso das ferramentas usadas na programação.

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre uma ferramenta. Tanto que foi fechada como fora do escopo.

Comment: O WSL não é uma ferramenta de programação?

Comment: porque não pode ter perguntas sobre ferramentas de programação? Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: @RobertoLeitedeMoraes https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/28595

Comment: Lá consta "Ferramentas normalmente usadas por desenvolvedores exercendo sua função programando, depurando, preparando ou implantando softwares e controlando o processo."

Comment: Mesmo que a pergunta fosse fora do tópico, o mais correto e gentil seria comentar, movê-la, ou fechá-la.

Comment: @Tony ela foi fechada, basta conferir la em cima.

Comment: Fechada indevidamente, pois o WSL é uma ferramenta de programação, é o bash Linux no Windows.

Comment: como comentei na pergunta acho que com esse critério tem outras perguntas que tem que ser removidas também por ser fora de escopo como: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91887/como-posso-encontrar-o-utilizador-no-ubuntu-shell-bash?rq=1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91887/como-posso-encontrar-o-utilizador-no-ubuntu-shell-bash?rq=1)

Comment: @Tony achei uma resposta que gostei mais do que a sua [https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-linux-bash-in-windows?newreg=9963e4af5b164a05acd2e6d7b072d874](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-linux-bash-in-windows?newreg=9963e4af5b164a05acd2e6d7b072d874)

Comment: OK, após rodar estes comandos do link que você achou (eu também havia visto esta antes, mas achei mais complicada), me diga se esta funcionou para você.

Comment: a outra que eu encontrei funcionou, vou testar a sua também

Comment: @Tony acabei de fazer a sua sugestão. realmente parece mais fácil, são dois comandos, mas na hora de executar demora muito mais, tem que re-iniciar a máquina, e depois fazer a configuração do bash, resumindo. tem uma vantagem que com a nova configuração você tem um controle maior do que você fez, mas no final o outra achei menos complicado e muito mais rápido.

Comment: OK, você pode responder sua própria pergunta e marcar como resposta, para ajudar os outros que buscarem por isto. Pode dar um +1 na minha resposta também.

Comment: @Tony assim que tiver pontuação suficiente vou fazer isso, obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.